# How can I find out email_verified using AWS SDK for JavaScript?

Tags: amazon-cognito

How can I find out the value of `email_verified` for a user using the AWS SDK for JavaScript?

I haven't found anything in the docs, but I assume this must be possible to check somehow. I would like to redirect the user to a verification page when the email is not verified.

I get a bunch of data when a user logs in, but I unfortunately don't get any information about whether the email is verified:

```
export function* authenticateUser(username: string, password: string) {
    const authenticationData = {
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    };

    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
    console.log({authenticationDetails: authenticationDetails});

    return yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const cognitoUser = getCognitoUser(username);
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: (result) => {
                console.log({result: result});
                const idToken = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken(); // To get an ordinary token

                resolve({
                    idToken,
                    refreshToken: result.getRefreshToken().getToken(),
                });
            },
            onFailure: (err) => {
                reject(err);
            },
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to call `cognitoUser.getUserAttributes` after the user is authenticated. The response would include the value of `email_verified`

Comment: I get an array of CognitoUserAttributes. One of them is {name: email, value:some_address@domain.com}. But it says nothing about email verified.

Comment: Is email verification enabled on the user pool? If you look at the user in question in the AWS web console what value for email_verified do they have?

Comment: The user has email_verified: false when I look in the Cognito web UI. I can see this in the "Users and groups section". email_verified is however not listed in the "Attributes section".

Comment: One more thing to check: does the app client you are using to access the user pool have the ability to read the email_verified attribute? In the Cognito configuration you can restrict the ability of clients to read/write certain attributes

Comment: @BrianWinant - Your comment helped me out with my issue. I had to check the `email verified` setting on the user pool on aws console. After that my client was able to see that UserAttribute